# jQuery-UI dialog current height and width

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I want to show the current height and width of jQuery-UI dialog in real time inside dialog box. How can I do the same. I mean if I increase the height by dragging then current height will be updated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out: http://jsfiddle.net/bryanjamesross/ngrkf/

Should be enough to get you started. What you're looking for mainly is the `resize` event of the jQueryUI dialog.

Check docs here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#event-resize

---

HTML:

```
<div id="dlg">
    Width: <span id="w"></span><br />
    Height: <span id="h"></span>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#dlg').dialog({
    resize: function(e,ui) {
        $('#w').text(Math.round(ui.size.width));
        $('#h').text(Math.round(ui.size.height));
    } 
});
```